# Opening file handle on every request vs. one time only

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, sftp, fs

This is regarding the SFTP protocol where you can download files from a server.

The SFTP client will issue multiple "read" requests, probably to download the file faster in multiple pieces.

In a normal scenario the server gets one OPEN request, then multiplie READ requests, then CLOSE.

So in the OPEN request, the server "opens" the local file handle (`fs.open`) and in the CLOSE request it close it (`fs.close`)... But what if the client is naughty and wants to do nasty stuff and just sends multiple OPEN requests for many files to make the server run out of memory?

In that case I think that best solution is for the server to open the file handle in the READ request and close it immediately after it's done reading. But will create other problems? I mean since multiple READ requests can run in parallel, there could be many file handles open that point to the same local file.

Comment: My initial thought is that a file handle won't use much memory. You will probably get an error that you run out of file handles before you run out of memory? But I could be very wrong.

Comment: Are your clients going to be connecting as "real" (corresponding OS account) users, (i.e. the individual user has file permissions) or lightweight/guest users, where your server is managing what clients can see within things accessible from its own OS permissions?

Answer (score 1):

To send files to client you can use `createReadStream` instead of doing `fs.open` and `fs.close`, something like this

```
// in response section...
res.writeHead(200, headers);
fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res)
```

Comment: Problem is I cannot use offset/length with that

Answer (score 1):

fs.createReadStream() can handle start and end bytes to handle each subsequent READ request.  See below.  Additionally, ensuring a malicious user is not making a request, you should handle this prior to reading the file data. If this is going to be anonymous SFTP You could perform a check on the requesters IP and limit a single IP to a single OPEN/READ stream per IP...  OR limit a single IP/Filepath combo. Just store this in a local variable, then on Open, add to the log and upon completing the download, remove them.

```
fs.createReadStream('sample.txt', {
  'flags': 'r',          //<string> See support of file system flags. Default: 'r'.
  'encoding': null,      // <string> Default: null
  'autoClose': true,     // <boolean> Default: true
  'emitClose': false,    // <boolean> Default: false
  'start': 0,            // <integer>
  'end': Infinity,       // <integer> Default: Infinity
  'highWaterMark': (64 * 1024),   // <integer> Default: 64 * 1024
});
```

---

```
An example to read the last 10 bytes of a file which is 100 bytes long:

fs.createReadStream('sample.txt', { start: 90, end: 99 });
```

Source: [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)

---

**Instead Use: ftp-srv**

All that being said, I think you are going to be much better off using a great FTP Package called ***ftp-srv*** that handles all this and more. I have used it in production where hundreds of users and thousands of daily downloads/uploads each day without issue.  Based on the considerations factored in your post, you will not be able to protect against a malicious user.  Especially when it comes to FTP/SFTP, there is ton of malicious request that come in almost every second by scanning bots.  You need to have a way to BAN IP's you find to be malicious. ftp-srv will handle all this and more.

**The best Node FTP Server in my experience is: [ftp-srv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv)**

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv

*I have no affiliation with the package.*

Answer (score 1):

> In that case I think that best solution is for the server to open the file handle in the READ request and close it immediately after it's done reading.

For sure!

> But will create other problems?

Why it should?

> I mean since multiple READ requests can run in parallel, there could be many file handles open that point to the same local file.

The only problem is that once the limit on open files (I guess you know `ulimit`) is hit, your server will get an error on next open attempt. Before that limit is hit, if descriptors are for distinct files (or sockets, or pipes, or devices...) or all for the same file, makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an SFTP server and need to give access to others to read from the server,

You must create a public key-private key and give the public key to clients, and/or create passwords. Only genuine clients should open connection on your server (limiting DDOS type of attacks),

Also, while coding even SFTP must be treated like Database and connection should be shared (connection pooling), I mean to say Open connection once and then do as many read-writes and then close the connection. So even if one needs to read-write files asynchronously, must first open connection and read-write asynchronously and close connection when completed, you can also go with read-write in stream if use-case permits.

I am not elaborating on how to do stream read-write or anything as previous answers have mentioned them beautifully.